# Get WebBrowser.Document from another HTMLpage

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

My application opens up a HTML page as a popup and it is getting opened in a different window. (Browser : IE8)

I need to read the HTML content of this popup and close it afterwards.

I have been looking at different alternative of using FindWindow functions etc but no luck yet.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're opening the popup, but this article should help: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

Notice how you have to declare a new variable, `newwindow`, that holds a reference to the popup window. From there, it's a simple `$(window).html().

You might add this to the onclick() of a link.

```
var newwindow = window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
if (window.focus) {
    newwindow.focus();
}
var html = $(newwindow).html();
return false; // if it's a link, you have to prevent it from opening the link's 
              //address in the original window
```

Edit: if you're not the one opening the popup, things are more iffy. You can get a reference to the topmost window using `window.top`, but that's about all I know, especially because the situation isn't quite clear.

Comment: In my case, popup is opened by different application and I just need to read HTML content within.

Comment: @darshan See my edit. If this is even possible, it might take more clarification about the timeline of events and how everything is happening.